# How to use the fab style diamond?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

How to use diamond style for fab + bottom app bar? In the sketch files on the website https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/ there are such styles fab:
[image]

Looked at all possible styles and tags...

Comment: I suspect that you have to create that yourself, probably using a custom background. I don't see anything for shape with [the Material Components' edition of `FloatingActionButton`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/).

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I should not create it myself .. it works in conjunction with the bottom app bar and the animation of the disappearance ...

Comment: Well, there's MaterialShapeDrawable with EdgeTreatment and CornerTreatment (in Material Components 1.1), but it takes some time to learn the API and make something nice with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to Gabriele Mariotti. I used his code and changed it a little bit to give the rounded look to bottom app bar like in the original question.

Firstly for the FAB I gave it rounded [corners](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#theming-fabs) and rotated it 45 degrees like this:

XML code for fab:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fabHome"
        android:rotation="45"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBarHome"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/FabDiamondOverlay"/>
```

The FabDiamondOverlay is:

```
<style name="FabDiamondOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">15%</item>
</style>
```

which gives the resulting FAB:

[image: Diamond rounded FAB]

Now for the bottom bar XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        app:fabCradleMargin="20dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

and this code in OnCreate method to give bottom app bar a custom look:

```
    BottomAppBar bar = findViewById(R.id.bottomBarHome);

    BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment topEdge = new BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge(
            bar.getFabCradleMargin(),
            bar.getFabCradleRoundedCornerRadius(),
            bar.getCradleVerticalOffset());

    MaterialShapeDrawable bottomBarBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bar.getBackground();
    bottomBarBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
            bottomBarBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,75)
                    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,75)
                    .setTopEdge(topEdge)
                    .build());
```

Where `BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge` is by modifying Gabrielle's code:
[Source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge.java)

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("RestrictTo")
    public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation, ShapePath shapePath) {
        float fabDiameter = getFabDiameter();
        if (fabDiameter == 0) {
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return;
        }

        float diamondSize = fabDiameter / 2f;
        float middle = center + getHorizontalOffset();

        float verticalOffsetRatio = cradleVerticalOffset / diamondSize;
        if (verticalOffsetRatio >= 1.0f) {
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return;
        }

        float barLeftVertex = middle - (fabMargin + diamondSize - cradleVerticalOffset);
        float barRightVertex = middle + (fabMargin + diamondSize - cradleVerticalOffset);
        float depth = (diamondSize - cradleVerticalOffset + fabMargin) * interpolation;

        float heightArc = 25;
        float widthArc = 25;

        shapePath.lineTo(barLeftVertex, 0);

        shapePath.lineTo(middle-widthArc, depth-heightArc);

        shapePath.addArc(middle-widthArc-10, 35, middle+widthArc+10, depth-15, 135, -83);

        shapePath.lineTo(middle+widthArc, depth-heightArc);
        shapePath.lineTo(barRightVertex, 0);

        shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
    }
```

The values here were decided with hit and trial. I couldn't understand what every variable did and there seems to be really less documentation about it. But it gets the job done! Here is the final result:

[image: Final image]

Answer (score 5):

Currently there isn't a official shape for the `BottomAppBar`.

However with the version **1.1.0** of the [material components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can customize the [shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) of the [`FloatingActionButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) using the **`app:shapeAppearance`** attribute.

You can use something like:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/FabDiamondOverlay"
        .../>
```

with this style:

```
 <style name="FabDiamondOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

It is the result:

[image]

Currently the shape theming attributes doesn't affect the `BottomAppBar` and you can only have rounded corners for the FAB cradle. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge.java) added in the official repository.

Just use a default BottomAppBar with the attribute **`app:fabCradleMargin`** (it defines the distance between the `FloatingActionButton` and the `BottomAppBar`)

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        ...
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        />
```

and use the [`BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge.java) to change the shape of the `BottomAppBar`:

```
    BottomAppBar bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
    FloatingActionButton fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment topEdge = new BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge(
            bar.getFabCradleMargin(),
            bar.getFabCradleRoundedCornerRadius(),
            bar.getCradleVerticalOffset());
    MaterialShapeDrawable babBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bar.getBackground();
    //It requires 1.1.0-alpha10
    babBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
      babBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setTopEdge(topEdge)
      .build());
```

It is the final result:

[image]

Comment: I did it right after the creation of the question:) How do you wrap the edge?

Comment: Do you mean automatically change the edge of the bottombar starting from the shape of the fab?

Comment: We need to make corners like a screenshot. It's rounded, not sharp

Comment: If you want to make corners like the screenshot just use the code in the answer with [this class](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge.java), it wraps the edge. Otherwise for rounded or flat corners just use the standard component.

Comment: @RomanK. I am not sure if my comment is clear and you are able to wrap the edge in the bar.