# Quastion aboud FloatingActionButton (diamond)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design, floating-action-button

I trying to make FAB with diamond shape.

[image]

A lot of articles is saying the same:

[image]

**Ok, let's go to my code:**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addCost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/FabDiamondOverlay"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/BottomAppBarTheme"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"/>
```

**And the result is:**

[image]

**Whats wrong with this FAB ? Why it is circle instead of diamond shape ?  It should be diamond, like examples in all articles all over Internet**
**My stile file looks like:**

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...
        <style name="FabDiamondOverlay" parent="">
            <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
            <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="BottomAppBarTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored">
            <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Currently the shape theming attributes doesn't affect the BottomAppBar and you can only have rounded corners for the FAB cradle.

All layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".presantation.FragmentCost">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addCost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/FabDiamondOverlay"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/BottomAppBarTheme"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Maybe the problem in theme file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SplitCost" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.SplitCost.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.SplitCost.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="Theme.SplitCost.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="FabDiamondOverlay" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomAppBarTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: For me, your code is working fine, can you share whole layout file -> [**OUTPUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXBI6.png)

Comment: @AskNilesh is your button diamond shape when you using my code ? I added whole code

Comment: Yes @elenaovchinnikova

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360333/12709358

Comment: @AskNilesh It's impossible, please look at my Theme and Layout files, I put it in quastion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! It is a bug of Android Studio. On real device this button is diamond !
If someone have a problem like it, don't worry/ Don't trust Android Studio Preview !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).